# Embed flash object doesn't play in Google Chrome

Tags: flash, google-chrome, object

On a site click-storm.ru I can't have object-videos in a slider start playing. They play great in Opera, IE and etc.
What is interesting, iframe videos play great in Chrome.
Object-videos play great outside the slider. Can't guess what's wrong =(
Here is a code of a slider:

```
<!-- wrapper -->
<div>
<!-- wrapper -->

<!-- slider -->
<div style="float:left; margin-left:50px;">
<!-- slider -->

<div id="banner-example-1" class="light">


            <ul>                                

                    <!-- THE 1. SLIDE -->
                    <li data-transition="slide"><img src="images/slides/big1.jpg" data-thumb="images/thumbs/s1b.jpg" data-thumb_bw="images/thumbs/s1g.jpg">

                            <div class="video_container">
                                <div class="video_container_wrap">  

<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="491" width="806" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=thorzain" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /> <param  name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=thorzain&auto_play=false&start_volume=25" />
</object>                                   
                                                                    </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div  class="creative_layer">
                                <div class="caption_blue fadeleft" style="top:120px;left:590px;">ThorZain</div>                 
                                <div class="caption_white faderight" style="top:120px;left:722px;">Английский</div>
                                <div class="caption_black smallcap fadeup" style="top:163px;left:590px;">Один из лучших терранов планеты</div>                                  
                            </div>

                    </li>



                    <!-- THE 2. SLIDE -->
                    <li data-transition="slide"><img src="images/slides/big2.jpg" data-thumb="images/thumbs/s2b.jpg" data-thumb_bw="images/thumbs/s2g.jpg">

                            <div class="video_container">
                                <div class="video_container_wrap2"> 
                                    <iframe height="468" width="832" frameborder="0" src="http://www.own3d.tv/liveembed/172637"></iframe>

                                                                    </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div  class="creative_layer">
                                <div class="caption_blue fadeleft" style="top:120px;left:590px;">MillForGG</div>                    
                                <div class="caption_white faderight" style="top:120px;left:722px;">Английский</div>
                                <div class="caption_black smallcap fadeup" style="top:163px;left:590px;">Сильный корейский терран</div>                                 
                            </div>

                    </li>

<!-- THE 3. SLIDE -->
                    <li data-transition="slide"><img src="images/slides/big3.jpg" data-thumb="images/thumbs/s3b.jpg" data-thumb_bw="images/thumbs/s3g.jpg">

                            <div class="video_container">
                                <div class="video_container_wrap">  
                                    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="495" width="806" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=liquidret" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=liquidret&auto_play=false&start_volume=25" /></object>
                                                                    </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div  class="creative_layer">
                                <div class="caption_blue fadeleft" style="top:120px;left:590px;">LiquidRet</div>                    
                                <div class="caption_white faderight" style="top:120px;left:722px;">Английский</div>
                                <div class="caption_black smallcap fadeup" style="top:163px;left:590px;">Зерг из Голландии</div>                                    
                            </div>

                    </li>

<!-- THE 4. SLIDE -->
                    <li data-transition="slide"><img src="images/slides/big4.jpg" data-thumb="images/thumbs/s4b.jpg" data-thumb_bw="images/thumbs/s4g.jpg">

                            <div class="video_container">
                                <div class="video_container_wrap2"> 
                                    <iframe height="468" width="832" frameborder="0" src="http://www.own3d.tv/liveembed/136659"></iframe>

                                                                    </div>
                            </div>  

                            <div  class="creative_layer">
                                <div class="caption_blue fadeleft" style="top:120px;left:590px;">Virtus.Pro</div>                   
                                <div class="caption_white faderight" style="top:120px;left:722px;">Русский</div>
                                <div class="caption_black smallcap fadeup" style="top:163px;left:590px;">Трансляции от KTS и kaby</div>                                 
                            </div>

                    </li>                   
                </ul>
                <div class="bigleft"></div>
                <div class="bigright"></div>
            </div>      <!-- THE END OF THE BANNER EXMAPLE -->

            <!--
            ##############################
             - ACTIVATE THE BANNER HERE -
            ##############################
            -->
            <script type="text/javascript">

                var tpj=jQuery;
                tpj.noConflict();

                tpj(document).ready(function() {

                if (tpj.fn.cssOriginal!=undefined)
                    tpj.fn.css = tpj.fn.cssOriginal;

                    tpj('#banner-example-1').paradigm(
                        {                                       
                            width:832,
                            height:491,

                            thumbWidth:90,
                            thumbHeight:50,
                            thumbAmount:4,                          
                            thumbSpaces:4,
                            thumbPadding:4,
                            thumbStyle:"thumb",
                            thumbVideoIcon:"on",
                            bulletXOffset:0,
                            bulletYOffset:0,

                            shadow:'true',

                            parallaxX:500,
                            parallaxY:10,
                            captionParallaxX:-40,
                            captionParallaxY:2,

                            touchenabled:'on',

                            timer:10                        
                        });




            });
            </script>
<!-- slider -->
</div>
<!-- slider -->


<!-- chat -->
<div style="float:right;">
<!-- chat -->


    <!-- BEGIN CBOX - www.cbox.ws - v001 -->
<div id="cboxdiv" style="text-align: center; line-height: 0">
<div><iframe frameborder="0" width="230" height="453" src="http://www7.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=549330&amp;boxtag=f0tgr5&amp;sec=main" marginheight="2" marginwidth="2" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="yes" name="cboxmain7-549330" style="border:#ababab 1px solid;" id="cboxmain7-549330"></iframe></div>
<div><iframe frameborder="0" width="230" height="107" src="http://www7.cbox.ws/box/?boxid=549330&amp;boxtag=f0tgr5&amp;sec=form" marginheight="2" marginwidth="2" scrolling="no" allowtransparency="yes" name="cboxform7-549330" style="border:#ababab 1px solid;border-top:0px" id="cboxform7-549330"></iframe></div>
</div>
<!-- END CBOX -->

<!-- chat -->
</div>
<!-- chat -->

<!-- wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- wrapper -->

<div style="height:15px"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try first embedding your flash movie with [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)? This is the most accepted way for it and it's very well [documented](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/documentation). It's also the most standard way and proved to work in most scenarios.

You can embed your movies both statically and dinamically, though I usually prefer doing it dynamically. You can check both modes in the documentation.

For the dynamic mode, in your case, you'd need something like:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>`

> ```
> var flashvars = {};
>     flashvars.hostname= "www.twitch.tv";
>     flashvars.channel= "liquidret";
>     flashvars.auto_play= "false";
>     flashvars.start_volume= "25";
>     swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf", "video_container_wrap", "491", "806", "9.0.0", flashvars);
> ```

It also comes with its own [code generator](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/generator) that you could try.